# How to set eclipse plugins installation dir

Tags: eclipse

I use Keppler 4.3.2 on Linux.

I just installed Android ADT. Problem is, the plugins is installed on my home dir (~/plugins and ~/features). I want it to be installed on ~/.eclipse32/plugins and ~/.eclipse32/features respectively.

I've read the FAQ and help. Cannot find what i am looking for.

EDIT: Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform your installations, just make sure you are logged in as root.

I stumbled over this myself awhile back, it was quite frustrating!

Comment: Here is interesting multi-user post: http://divby0.blogspot.com/2007/08/howto-install-eclipse-for-multi-user.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've installed eclipse on /opt/eclipse as a root. Then run it as an ordinary user. I'd prefer using eclipse as a user. Shouldn't be any runtime configuration directive to set it ?

Comment: Thanks for the link justin. Now it works great. Thank you. :)